# AWS lambda failed after enabled VPC

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-vpc

I am getting connection timeout error with VPC enabled but working fine without enabled VPC.

```
{
  "errorMessage": "HTTPSConnectionPool(host='huggingface.co', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /bert-base-cased/resolve/main/tokenizer_config.json (Caused by ConnectTimeoutError(<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7fd7f0a07040>, 'Connection to huggingface.co timed out. (connect timeout=30)'))",
  "errorType": "ConnectTimeout",
  "requestId": "",
  "stackTrace": [
    "  File \"/var/lang/lib/python3.10/importlib/__init__.py\", line 126, in import_module\n    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)\n",
    "  File \"<frozen importlib._bootstrap>\", line 1050, in _gcd_import\n",
    "  File \"<frozen importlib._bootstrap>\", line 1027, in _find_and_load\n",
    "  File \"<frozen importlib._bootstrap>\", line 1006, in _find_and_load_unlocked\n",
    "  File \"<frozen importlib._bootstrap>\", line 688, in _load_unlocked\n",
    "  File \"<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>\", line 883, in exec_module\n",
    "  File \"<frozen importlib._bootstrap>\", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed\n",
    "  File \"/var/task/spellCorrection_rest_app.py\", line 4, in <module>\n    response = requests.head(url, timeout=30)  # Increase the timeout value as needed\n",
    "  File \"/var/task/requests/api.py\", line 100, in head\n    return request(\"head\", url, **kwargs)\n",
    "  File \"/var/task/requests/api.py\", line 59, in request\n    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)\n",
    "  File \"/var/task/requests/sessions.py\", line 589, in request\n    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)\n",
    "  File \"/var/task/requests/sessions.py\", line 703, in send\n    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)\n",
    "  File \"/var/task/requests/adapters.py\", line 507, in send\n    raise ConnectTimeout(e, request=request)\n"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
You need to create a NAT Gateway in either one of your Public subnets 'subnet-0a41b43c04095c248' and 'subnet-00303000' of the VPC. Please follow the documentation[1] to get the detailed steps of creating a NAT Gateway.

Edit the route tables of the private subnets which are associated with your Lambda function, to allow the traffic to the destination 0.0.0.0/0 with the target set to the NAT Gateway, that you created in the public subnet.
```

Ref:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/vpc-nat-gateway.html#nat-gateway-creating